# current and future "state" or "states"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Should the noun `state` be singular or plural in this sentence

> I have identified documents regarding computing technologies that will enhance my understanding of the current and future states of computing.

I think it should be plural, because I'm considering the current state and future state, i.e. two states.

I've seen it written in this way

> This creative current and future state infographic showcase the difference between the current and desired state.

I think that first use of `state` is correct, because there `state` is being used as an adjective. However, I am less sure about the second use. I should mention that in this context "state" refers to the condition or health of a business. I think the addition of the word "between" makes the singular more appropriate, because it emphasizes it's a binary choice between one or the other of two singular options.

Have I interpreted both of these cases correctly?

Comment: Not an adjective, but the future state in both cases is one version compared with the current one. 1 - We don't know the future or how many states are coming, so it's all one big uncertain **state**. 2 - If we are changing from A to B, we compare the before and after state. Otherwise, we might be comparing all the before states with all the after ... no good.

Comment: Think of "state of the art" in your first case. In the 2nd case the second "state" should technically be "states" since it's a noun, I agree.

Comment: Singular all around. You have an elliptical *state*: *the current [state] and future state of computing*.

Comment: (A) Check "I interviewed the Outgoing (Current) & the InComing (future) President or Presidents" : Plural is better (B) Check "We are making the current & future Home" : Singular is better because it is Singular (C) Check "We are making the current & the future homes" : Plural is better because it is Plural (D) Use "the current and future state of computing" if you think both will be similar (Singular) in some aspect , or use "the current and the future states of computing" if you think these are Different (Plural) (E) Singular : "the current & future" & Plural : "the current & the future" !

Comment: @Serguei: I just searched Google Books for [*the current and future **state/states of play***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+current+and+future+states+of+play%22) ("play" being the most idiomatic usage here that you'd expect to be resistant to pluralisation). GB claims to have 7 pages of results (10 to a page) for ***both*** versions. But when it comes down to it, they show ***one single result*** where the sought text can be read in context, ***for each alternative***.

Answer (score 1):

There are arguments for both singular *and* plural in OP's context. On the one hand it's obvious that unless technological progress ceases completely, the ***future*** state of technology will be different to the ***current*** state. So that's at least two different states straight away.

On the other hand, at any given moment in time there's only one state. It's a single thing like a person. So just as you might refer to your *past, present, and future **wife*** (only one wife, who persists / changes over time), we can adopt that position for a single persistent state of affairs. And as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=current%20and%20future%20states%20of%2Ccurrent%20and%20future%20state%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows, that's what most of us do...

[image]

---

Singular/plural isn't entirely an arbitrary stylistic choice here. There's at least the *potential* for a nuance of difference, in that at least *some* people will understand the relatively less common plural usage as more strongly emphasizing the ***difference*** between what we have now and what lies ahead. But many (most?) people probably just use one version all the time, so that's a spurious distinction to them.